# Matplotlib Auto Annotate max doesn't annotate and pushes chart off page

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I'm trying to auto annotate matplotlib chart.

I've manage to create it in a way that that doesn't give me any errors when I run it.

However, it doesn't plot the annotation and as I'm plotting in jupyter notebooks it pushes the plot right off the page.

The result I'm looking for is an automatically assigning annotation pointing to the max number in the series `ppc_rolling_7d` on the chart.

I'm kinda out of ideas as to what has happened here.

example data:

```
ppc_data = pd.DataFrame({
'Day':['2018-08-31', '2018-09-01', '2018-09-02', '2018-09-03',
'2018-09-04', '2018-09-05', '2018-09-06', '2018-09-07',
'2018-09-08', '2018-09-09', '2018-09-10', '2018-09-11',
'2018-09-12', '2018-09-13', '2018-09-14', '2018-09-15',
'2018-09-16', '2018-09-17', '2018-09-18', '2018-09-19',
'2018-09-20', '2018-09-21', '2018-09-22', '2018-09-23',
'2018-09-24', '2018-09-25', '2018-09-26', '2018-09-27',
'2018-09-28', '2018-09-29', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-01',
'2018-10-02', '2018-10-03', '2018-10-04', '2018-10-05',
'2018-10-06', '2018-10-07', '2018-10-08', '2018-10-09',
'2018-10-10', '2018-10-11', '2018-10-12', '2018-10-13',
'2018-10-14', '2018-10-15', '2018-10-16', '2018-10-17',
'2018-10-18', '2018-10-19', '2018-10-20', '2018-10-21',
'2018-10-22', '2018-10-23', '2018-10-24', '2018-10-25',
'2018-10-26', '2018-10-27', '2018-10-28', '2018-10-29',
'2018-10-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02',
'2018-11-03', '2018-11-04', '2018-11-05', '2018-11-06',
'2018-11-07', '2018-11-08', '2018-11-09', '2018-11-10',
'2018-11-11', '2018-11-12', '2018-11-13', '2018-11-14',
'2018-11-15', '2018-11-16', '2018-11-17', '2018-11-18',
'2018-11-19', '2018-11-20', '2018-11-21', '2018-11-22',
'2018-11-23', '2018-11-24', '2018-11-25', '2018-11-26',
'2018-11-27', '2018-11-28', '2018-11-29', '2018-11-30',
'2018-12-01', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04',
'2018-12-05', '2018-12-06', '2018-12-07', '2018-12-08'],

'Cost' : [1105.8097834013993, 1035.8355715930172, 2335.4700418958632,
 655.0721024605979, 1154.3067936459986, 2275.8927050269917,
 174.47816810392712,1606.0865381579742,973.1285739075876,
 677.3734705782231,2381.149891233519, 1137.840620239881,
 673.0575320194132, 1969.3783478235364, 1667.3405411738886,
 1365.707089062391, 1686.492803446683, 1613.2530220414621, 
 2275.475164597224, 1593.9382082221036, 1278.8267306408893,
 1342.2964464944962, 863.9840442789089, 289.34425736432837,
 15.219941807702485, 1595.2327617943374, 1592.8333476628231,
 961.5931139385652, 703.2690737772505, 312.9730830647801,
 2105.920303495205, 707.710807657391, 873.7377744639931,
 152.51387772605813, 1292.4027169055073, 1142.7323830723421,
 2400.462099397225, 2027.5730000421765, 2380.127923249452,
 370.97680360266463, 978.7472607817784, 144.50724935561453,
 1257.3962926696906, 339.44922335906256, 989.3364341529344,
 1274.7020560588671, 1697.9640365081489, 81.00819304765376,
 528.9126509191693, 893.839100786781, 1778.7263797734338,
 1388.1976452584615, 533.7823940180391, 1390.507110740847,
 1582.8069647428326, 2058.124928605663, 1456.0037174730746,
 315.93672830017414,488.9620970966599, 2020.6125475658266,
 1358.8988386729175,1967.1442608919235,436.40540549351783,
 2090.41730824453,2114.3435803364277,2235.719648814769,
 1773.3190866160382,2372.165649889117, 1186.850504563462,
 864.4092140750176, 772.6148714908818,1749.9856862684244,
 802.1475898419487, 1013.3410373277948, 1604.4137362997474,
 1880.084707526689, 1823.9691856540412,550.6041906641643,
 75.26104973616485, 819.9409527114842, 2272.8529542934198,
 1836.7071931445969,1491.3728333359875, 1807.2130424285615,
 2378.1185581431337,1434.1809462567153,296.49945129452675,
 2025.2054514729998,2346.234514785023, 2438.058561262957,
 277.36529451533386, 1212.541281523483,2005.258496330315,
 2053.7325650486177,2076.001012737591, 2245.606468047353,
 2493.336539619115,1116.075112703116,319.54750552662733,
 648.633853658328]}

).set_index('Day')

ppc_data.index = pd.to_datetime(ppc_data.index)


ppc_weekly = ppc_data['Cost'].resample('W').mean()
ppc_rolling_7d = ppc_data['Cost'].rolling(window=7, center=True).mean()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

figsize = (15,8)

ppc_data['Cost'].plot(figsize=figsize, 
                      alpha=.5, 
                      marker='.', 
                      linestyle='-', 
                      linewidth=0.5, 
                      label='Daily'
                     )

ppc_weekly.plot(figsize=figsize,
                marker='x',
                markersize=8, 
                linestyle='-',
                label='Weekly Mean Resample'
               )

ppc_rolling_7d.plot(figsize=figsize,
                   marker='o',
                   linestyle='-',
                   label='7-d Rolling Mean'
                  )

max_value = ppc_rolling_7d.max()
max_value_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(ppc_rolling_7) if j == max_value]


#Create ax customatisations
ax.annotate('Lots of Pageviews but few clicks',
            xy=(max_value_index[0],max_value),
            xytext=(max_value_index[0],max_value),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='cyan', #colour
                            shrink=0.05, #length of arrow
                            lw=1, #line width
                            ec='magenta', #boarder colour
                            zorder=1)) #layering order of annotation



#Global Plot settings
plt.title('COMPARE: Daily, Weekly Mean, 7-d Rolling Mean ') # set chart name
fig.legend() # set the legend

#display the charts
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions to what could be the problem are welcome.

Comment: Where would you expect `(-20,20)` to be in your chart?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry. I've changed that. I was dappling just before I posted. I've changed it to be my last official try ☺️ ...the output was the same for both.

Comment: Ok, I would need to run your code to investigate; but unfortunately it's not runnable by itself. Even if I replace some obvious variable names like `ppc_rolling_7` -> `ppc_rolling_7d` it says "no numeric values to plot". See [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'll sort this right now.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry that took so long. I've check that the data works and it does :) I've also updated some of the code adding previous steps so you can see how I got the data I'm plotting.

Comment: It seems `max_value` is 94? So how would 94 relate to the September 2018? Maybe you need to still explain a bit where you would expect the annotation to be located?

Comment: I've updated the Q but essentailly I'm looking for is an automatically assigning annotation pointing to the max number in the series `ppc_rolling_7d` on the chart. I could've messed up the list comprehension calculation but I thought it would still draw the point but it didn't do that.

Comment: I think you want to annotate the point `x = ppc_rolling_7d.idxmax(); y = ppc_rolling_7d.max()`

Comment:  Dude that's it! I completely forgot about idxmax(). It works thanks! Do you want to submit that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest who commented with the answer.

Using `idxmax()` will quickly find the index of the max value.

```
x = ppc_rolling_7d.idxmax(); y = ppc_rolling_7d.max()
```